# Group an R dataframe by genomic coordinates to plot mean coverage per base

Tags: r

I would like to plot a genomics region mean coverage per base along different samples: I would like to plot each genomic position in the x axis, and the mean coverage of it in the y axis.

I have this file: where the first column indicates the genomic region and the second column indicates de mean coverage along different samples.

```
12:36761802-36761804 54
12:36761802-36761805 42
12:36761802-36761806 56.5
12:36761802-36761810 28.75
12:36761803-36761804 29
12:36761803-36761806 30
```

As you can see, the rows are overlapped, so I am not sure about how could I plot this.

Answer (score 1):

You could plot the ranges as line segments:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df$region_start <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$region, "-"), `[`, 1)))
df$region_end <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$region, "-"), `[`, 2)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = region_start, y = mean, colour = region)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = region_end, yend = mean), size = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "locus")
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

After further clarification from the OP, it is the mean of the values at each point that should be plotted. This is a little more involved, but can be done in a few lines with `dplyr`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df$region_start <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$region, "-"), `[`, 1)))
df$region_end <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$region, "-"), `[`, 2)))
do.call("rbind", mapply(function(x, y, z) cbind(x:y, rep(z, 1 + y - x)),
                        df$region_start, 
                        df$region_end, 
                        df$mean)) %>%
  as.data.frame()                 %>%
  setNames(c("Locus", "Value"))   %>%
  group_by(Locus)                 %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Value))   %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Locus, y = mean)) + 
  geom_line() + labs(x = "Locus")
```

### [image]

Data used:

```r
           region  mean
36761802-36761804    54
36761802-36761805    42
36761802-36761806  56.5
36761802-36761810 28.75
36761803-36761804    29
36761803-36761806    30
```

Reprex:

```
df <- structure(list(region = c("36761802-36761804", "36761802-36761805", 
                "36761802-36761806", "36761802-36761810", "36761803-36761804", 
                "36761803-36761806"), mean = c(54, 42, 56.5, 28.75, 29, 30)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Can I perform this but just with the mean for each positions among all samples? I mean: I am interested on the average mean of each positions coverage among all samples, not in the coverage for each sample.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Allan but slightly different:

- Using segment width to denote the mean coverage.
- Numbering the samples and using that as y axis

```r
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")           

# Your data - thanks Allan
df <- structure(list(region = c("36761802-36761804", "36761802-36761805", 
                                "36761802-36761806", "36761802-36761810", "36761803-36761804", 
                                "36761803-36761806"), mean = c(54, 42, 56.5, 28.75, 29, 30)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))



df <- df %>%
  mutate(sample = factor(1:n())) %>%
  separate(region, into = c("rstart", "rend"))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = rstart, xend = rend, 
                   y = sample, yend = sample,
                   size = mean, color = mean)) +
  scale_size(guide = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>